# Windows 11 networking web servers

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11

I'm new to windows 11 (or whatever version), and can't figure out networking:

- I have a Stable Diffusion server running locally on port 7860
- I have a nodejs server running on port 3000 (whatever) over WSL2
- I can open both of them in the browser locally, on windows through `http://localhost:{PORT}`
- I can ping the windows IP from my mac and get pongs

I can't, though, access the urls from my browser in my macbook

- I tried disabling the Windows Firewall completely, to no avail

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: What _local address_ are both servers listening on? Have you tried adding specific Windows Firewall rules instead of disabling it outright?

Comment: what do you mean by local address? if i'm accessing the IP directly...

Comment: There's more than one "the IP" involved here – `localhost` does not go to the same address as your LAN IP address (it goes to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 instead). Servers can choose to accept connections either at all local addresses, or at only a specific one. Does the nodejs server show a "listening on <address>:<port>" when it starts? If not, find it in `netstat -a -n -p tcp` and check what address it's on.

Comment: shows http://172.17.219.156:3000 and i can access that address locally on windows, again, not from other machines

Comment: running `netstat -a -n -p tcp` couldn't find anything under port 3000, i don't know how to read it...

Comment: Oh, right, I completely overlooked that this was on WSL2, not WSL1. That's a rather different situation...

Comment: what about other ports and/or protocols...  can you access anything (except icmp/ping)?

Comment: Please don't just add the information to the comments please also edit and include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> 172.17.219.156:3000 and i can access that address locally on windows, again, not from other machines

WSL2 runs as a Hyper-V VM, and by default it is placed on a virtual network separate from your physical LAN. The host itself knows where the 172.17.219.x network is, but the rest of your LAN *does not.*

(Normally the host OS and the WSL2 VM also have their own separate 'localhost's, but WSL automatically forwards all 'localhost' connections from host to listeners on the guest to make it appear as a single system.)

It seems that you can configure WSL2 to use an "external" Hyper-V bridge instead, placing the VM directly in your physical network, as per [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-1310028257):

> Example working `.wslconfig` for localhost:
>
> ```
> [wsl2]
> # Bridged networking
> networkingMode=bridged
> vmSwitch=WSL_external
> dhcp=true
>
> # Turn off default connection to bind WSL 2 localhost to Windows localhost
> localhostforwarding=true
> ```
>
> and `/etc/wsl.conf`
>
> ```
> [boot]
> systemd=true
> [network]
> generateResolvConf = false
> ```
>
> and `/usr/lib/systemd/network/wsl_external.network`
>
> ```
> [Match]
> Name=eth0
>
> [Network]
> Description=WSL
> DHCP=true
> ```

Another approach that I've seen is to use Windows' built-in TCP proxy support via `netsh interface portproxy` to have the host automatically forward certain connections to the guest.